# Inserting Registered Trademark Symbol/Copyright Symbol into MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I am having a hard time understanding how to insert the registered trademark sybol and copyright symbol to my mySQL database using php.

When I insert the normal character of the reistered trademark symbol, it returns some random values when I try to retrieve it.

Comment: Which kind of _random values_?

Comment: What character set is your db table using?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can look into converting the copyright/trademark symbol from and into an HTMLEntity in order to ease data transfer to the database.

**Reference**: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

**Reference**: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

© Copyright Symbol: `&#169`;

™ Trademark Symbol: `&#153`;

Comment: What about when we don't want to output results as HTML?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are seeing the BOM and showing values like '\xEF\xBF\xBD' (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark for background info)

You may want to check your character set to ensure it encompasses the values, try UTF8 rather than latin or whatever you are using and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Where would the BOM come from? MySQL doesn't use BOM, so it wouldn't be inserted by MySQL. And if it comes from his code editor, it would be the first character in his source code, which wouldn't be able to find its way into the database.

Comment: I had similar issues trying to insert the registered trademark symbol, I was getting an incorrect string value from MySQL with the BOM listed. The data being passed to MySQL is the origination of the issue, but the issue is being reported in MySQL.